# Why aren't these members of my controller class getting initialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to debug my controller that looks like

```
namespace MrProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {

        private bool isAuthenticated;
        private string bundleGuid;

        PortalData PD = new PortalData();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string bguid)
        {
            // bguid: bundle guid, the guid corresponding to one or more assets in the table 


            isAuthenticated = false;
            bundleGuid = bguid;
```

and I've noticed that the members `isAuthenticated` and `bundleGuid` are not being initialized by the lines

```
            isAuthenticated = false;
            bundleGuid = bguid;
```

Why is that? Let me know if I need to post other parts of my code.

Comment: They won't get initialized during Controller instantiation but rather when the Index action is invoked.

Comment: They're not getting initialized by `Index`, though. If they were, they should be getting invoked when I load the page that corresponds to the controller. Right?

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on `isAuthenticated = false;`, it will get initialized to false **for the duration of the web request and only to /My/Index(string bguid)!**.  It will not be initialized for any other request based on what you've shown so far.

Comment: @DavidL So what's the solution?

Comment: Based on what you've shown, we still don't know how you're calling the controller and when you expect them to be initialized.  So we still don't have a complete problem statement or a complete code sample to reproduce the problem statement.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidL I want them initialized during the invocation of `Index`

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Do you see this code executed and simply don't like values that are set OR you don't see this code executed at all?